# How to distribute files with custom icon in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, icons, desktop-customization

I know how to assign a custom icon to a folder on my own computer. But is there a way to *distribute* a folder that has a custom icon without having to manually assign the custom icon on each new computer?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible by editing the `desktop.ini` file.

1. Create a new folder. 
   Place a file containing your icon of choice into the folder. 
   This file can be of type `.bmp`, `.dll`, `.exe`, or `.ico`. 
   Of these, all except `.bmp` can contain multiple icons.
2. Create a new document in Notepad.
3. Type

   ```
   [.ShellClassInfo]
   IconFile=iconfilename
   IconIndex=number
   ```

   or

   ```
   [.ShellClassInfo]
   IconResource=iconfilename,number
   ```

   where *`iconfilename`* is the name (including the extension) of the icon file, and *`number`* is the index of the icon to use. 
   Specify 0 (zero) to use the first icon in the file,
   1 for the second, and so on. 
   If you want the first icon,
   you can leave out the `,0` (with the `IconResource` form),
   and you may be able to leave out the `IconIndex` line in the `IconFile` form.
4. Save as `Desktop.ini` into the folder.

More information can be found on
[How to Use Desktop.ini to Customize Folder Icons](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/customize-folder-icons-desktop-ini/).

Now distribute the folder with the icon and `.ini` file in it.

Comment: Mind posting the contents of that link, in case it ever goes offline

Comment: ah ok I'll edit the answer to include the steps.

Comment: I’ve found (on Windows 7) that specifying `IconFile` without `IconIndex` doesn’t work, but specifying `IconResource` without a number does work.

Comment: Should this work on Windows 8? I've tried multiple combinations of the solutions above and none seem to work. Should changes to desktop.ini take effect immediately? Or do I need to restart or something?

Comment: I finally got it working but there is a critical extra step: Run `attrib +r TheNameOfYourFolder` after you update the desktop.ini file

Comment: Last problem: the desktop.ini seems to be lost when I copy the folder or zip and then extract it. Is there a workaround for this? Ideally I would like to be able to distribute the file via email...

Comment: @emersonthis Is there a checkbox on your zip utility for "Include system and hidden files"?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I was using Windows 8.

None of the above solutions worked for me. I was attempting to assign custom icons to folders stored on a flash drive and was only successful in assigning one to the drive itself.  What I ended up doing was going into properties and assigning the icon that I wanted to the file, storing said icons in the root of the flash drive and making them hidden.  Then I searched for the file mentioned in the above solutions (F:\name of file\desktop.ini) even though as far as I could tell that file did not exist (yes, I have hidden icons turned on).  I did find such a file and opened it in notepad.  it read:

[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=F:\Logo.ico,0

All I had to do was erase the drive info (as each computer decides what letter to assign the drive) so that it read:

[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=Logo.ico,0

I saved it and it kept the information from one computer to the next.

Now, I realize that this is literally the exact same code mentioned above, however when I made my own file in notepad and pasted the code in, saved it, and put it in the file, it didn't work.  The way I have suggested doing it somehow makes the desktop.ini file hidden even when you have hidden files enabled.  I don't understand that at all, but it works so I don't really care.